# How do I configure grub so it doesn't try to run if the drive its installed on is disconnected

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, startup

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.0 something in my PC where I upgraded my previous version 12.10.

Nothing is wrong with Ubuntu itself. It's grub, that's the problem. I keep my Ubuntu on a separate partition in an external hard drive around the size of 1TB. Grub is also located in this drive. But my problem is that grub attempts to start up on the computer even though it isn't there which means I have to plug in my hard drive every time I restart.

Is there any way I can work around this configuration? Or will it go away if I reinstall Ubuntu on the partition but in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

You have installed Grub to the internal hard disk rather than the removable one.  You need to reinstall grub to the removable drive, which you can do by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` and selecting the correct drive at the menu, and then restore whatever boot loader was originally on the internal drive.  Assuming that is Windows, you can use the Windows recovery console command FIXMBR to do that.